# NodeJS socket FIN_WAIT2

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a running nodejs server for socket communication with clients. After a period of time (few days) nodejs gets to 100% CPU usage. Looking at netstat for node port I found more than 1k connections with FIN_WAIT2 status (there should be only about 50 active connections). I'm using timeout function for connections, calling end() after specific timeout. But it doesn't seems to close the connection. So is end() valid way to close socket connection or should something else be used?

Comment: FIN_WAIT_2 state is reached after the close, not before. It means this node has sent a FIN and is waiting for the peer to send a FIN.

Comment: Here what I think is problem. Client that connects to node server losses net and reconnects later again. Is see same IP multiple times in netstat, only different port from which connection is coming. For example: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22810 and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22004. Is there any way to "force close", so that connection doesn't go into FIN_WAIT2 status?

Comment: The *peer* should close the socket when it reads EOS from it.

Comment: After intensive testing I found problem. It was not due to connection loss, but due to modal windows on client app. It disabled socket communication for period of time and node was time-outing connection (when modal window closed client would open new connection or use existing one if it was alive). I was closing connection with end() but that would just leave it in FIN_WAIT2 status. After end() I added destroy() to force close it and there are no more FIN_WAIT2 connections, or if there are they get removed after tcp_fin_timeout.